# Should we embed GA4 into an iframe of a page even though this page has already embedded another GA4 account?

Tags: javascript, web, iframe, google-analytics-4

I'm researching "Can I embed one more GA4 account into an iframe of the page even though this page has already embedded another GA4 account?"

I researched that we shouldn't use two GA4 accounts on a page, as it will lead to tracking inaccurate metrics.

In this scenario, a GA4 account (account A) is embedded in an iframe of a page and this page is also using a different GA4 account (account B). Does it lead to influences of tracking Analytics?

Comment: Is the embedded page on a different site than the parent page? Ex: www.domainA.com and www.domainB.com...

Comment: @A_Patterson Yes, this embedded page is different site than the parent page
Ex:The embedded page is "abc.io"
The parent page is "cde.com"